# Как ограничить создание div?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в базе данных есть 2 таблицы связанные между собой. Есть поле Id_ingr в котором записан id записей, которые относятся только к 1 одной записи из другой таблицы. Я прохожусь по ним foreach'ем и создаю див, нужно чтоб выводило 3 дива с разными данными но выводит дивов 25 если не больше(повторяется один и тот же ингредиент 3раза почему то), как это исправить?

```
             <?php 
        
        $sql ="SELECT dish_name,img,id_food,cost,ingredient,id_ingr FROM Food,ingredient";
            if($result = $conn3->query($sql))
           ?><?php   foreach($result as $row ):?>

        <div class="plate" >
                    <img class="img" src="<?php echo $row['img']; ?>"  alt="">
                    <h3 class="title" name="name"><?php echo $row['dish_name']; ?></h3>
                    <textarea type="text" class="discript" readonly><?php echo $row['ingredient']; ?></textarea>
                    <span class="price" >1000р</span>
                    <button  name="<?php $row['id_food'];?>"  class="button_for_buy">Заказать</button>
                </div> 
           <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Это не помогло, он просто повторяет 1ю запись 3жды, если изменю лимит на 4 добавиться следующая запись  и опять по новой.

Comment: `SELECT dish_name, img, id_food, cost, GROUP_CONCAT(ingredient SEPARATOR ', ') as ingredient  FROM Food, ingredient  GROUP BY id_food` что-то типа такого можно, для чего-то более конкретного добавляйте create двух таблиц + insert данные

Comment: спасибо большое